# Getting more than 100 data points to only represent part of 100%

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to graph stance phase of gait, which in only about 60% of the entire gait cycle (heel strike of one foot to heel strike of the same foot) But in the data out put there are 140 cells or data points that represent ONLY the stance phase and need the x-axis in the graph to go from 0-100% for the gait cycle while the 140 data points (cells with data) to represent 60% of the 100% of the gait cycle. How can I get the x-axis to go from 0-100% and get the 140 cells to represent only a fraction of the 100%?

Any Ideas would be great! Thanks!

Comment: If the X axis of the chart should show as 0 to 100%, then the data must be plotted as an XY Scatter Chart with numerical values for both X and Y. Depending on the nature of the data, you may need to do a conversion to a percentage before plotting. It would help to see a data sample and and idea of what the desired chart should look like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're saying you are plotting data which runs from 60-100 on the horizontal axis, but you want the horizontal axis to be displayed from 0 to 100.

If you right-click the horizontal axis on your plot and choose "Format Axis", you can manually set the the minimum and maximum values for the axis.

For more details, Microsoft provides a thorough explanation in the article "[Change the scale of a chart value axis](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-the-scale-of-a-chart-value-axis-HP005199141.aspx)". If your plot is a scatterplot, the instructions for the Y-axis apply equally to the X-axis.